# Doctrine behavior *translation entity error: No identifier/primary key specified for Entity

Tags: doctrine, behavior

After taking a src/bundle version of my bundle that makes use of the Knp translatable of the doctrine/behavior bundle. In the original bundle I everything works. 
But when calling :

```
app/console doctrine:schema:validate
```

it would throw an error:

```
No identifier/primary key specified for Entity
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seem to have been with the listeners not loading.

adding to config.yml

```
- { resource: ../../vendor/knplabs/doctrine-behaviors/config/orm-services.yml }
```

did the trick :)

Or the new way to modify AppKernel:

```
class AppKernel
{
    function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            //...
                new Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Bundle\DoctrineBehaviorsBundle(),
            //...
        );

        //...

        return $bundles;
    }
}
```

You can also register them using doctrine2 api:

```
<?php

$em->getEventManager()->addEventSubscriber(new     \Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\ORM\Translatable\TranslatableSubscriber);
// register more if needed
```

see: https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors#subscribers

Answer (score 1):

Its deprecated way as said at [knp behaviors documentation](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors#subscribers).

Add `new Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Bundle\DoctrineBehaviorsBundle(),` to AppKernel.php